# Does the first next() in js generator function always execute until the first yield?

Tags: javascript, generator

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) suggested that "When the iterator's next() method is called, the generator function's body is executed **until** the first yield expression" and I do understand this example:

```js
function* logGenerator() {
  console.log(0);
  console.log(1, yield);
  console.log(2, yield);
  console.log(3, yield);
}

var gen = logGenerator();

gen.next(); // 0
gen.next('pretzel'); // 1 pretzel
gen.next('california'); // 2 california
gen.next('mayonnaise'); // 3 mayonnaise
```

However, I am confused when I come across another example:

```js
const foo = function*() {
  yield 10;
  yield 20;
};

const bar = foo();
console.log(bar.next()); // {value: 10, done: false}
```

If the first `next()` only execute code **BEFORE** the first yield, the value should be undefined. How does it pick up the value **WITHIN** the first yield? I am a bit confused here. Thanks for helping out.

Comment: You seem to have stopped reading the sentence you quoted a little prematurely .... i.e. *When the iterator's next() method is called, the generator function's body is executed until the first yield expression, **which specifies the value to be returned from the iterator or, with yield\*, delegates to another generator function*** ... From this, we can infer that the `yield` itself is included in `until`, otherwise, if the execution stops before yield, then yield can't yield a value

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yeah...I thought about that, but if yield is included, then the first next() in the first example should give both `0` and `1, "pretzel"`. So I think I am missing something here...

Comment: you're confusing console output with when the yielded values are yielded

Comment: Ah my bad. Let me express in this way: If the first yield is included, then the first next() should already iterate the first yield. Shouldn't the second next() `gen.next('pretzel')` give `2 "pretzel"` instead?

Comment: `console.log(1, yield)` will not output to the console until after the **second** next is called - because `yield` is *evaluated* **before** console.log can run - look in the console output of https://jsfiddle.net/q91tf47r/

Comment: Now I see what you mean by "confusing console output"! The first next() has resolved the first yield, but the console.log will not be executed until the second next(). I tried to add a value with yield and it becomes pretty obvious. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't interpret that "until" very well. Never thought it's meant to be inclusive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see what's going on better by logging what the generator yields each time, as well as adding values to the `yield` expressions so you can see what the generator is actually yielding (the MDN example didn't bother with this because it never uses the yielded values, it was just demonstrating the way the `next()` argument works).

Typically, you wouldn't use a single generator to yield values and also receive values through the `next()` argument, just one or the other. If it yields values, you would use `yield <expression>` as a statement by itself (similar to `return`), not generally inside an expression. If it receives values you use `yield` without a parameter inside an expression. But as you can see with my modified example, the underlying mechanism allows both at the same time. You just need to keep track of the confusing order of execution.

```js
function* logGenerator() {
  console.log(0);
  console.log(1, yield 10);
  console.log(2, yield 20);
  console.log(3, yield 30);
}

var gen = logGenerator();

console.log("call 1 yielded", gen.next().value); // 0
console.log("call 2 yielded", gen.next('pretzel').value); // 1 pretzel
console.log("call 3 yielded", gen.next('california').value); // 2 california
console.log("call 4 yielded", gen.next('mayonnaise').value); // 3 mayonnaise
```

The first time you call the generator is executes `console.log(0);` and then starts executing `console.log(1, yield 10)`. But when it gets to the `yield` expression, `next()` returns that value, *before* actually calling `console.log()`.

The next time you call the generator, it resumes where it left off, which is constructing the arguments to `console.log()`. The `yield 10` expression is replaced with the argument to `next()`, so it executes `console.log(1, 'pretzel')`.

Then it starts executing `console.log(2, yield 20)`, and the same thing happens -- it yields `20` before calling `console.log()`.

What MDN was trying to show is that the argument to `next()` is only meaningful starting on the second call, because it replaces the value of `yield` in the interrupted expression when the generator resumes. Using an argument on the first call has no effect, because there's no interrupted expression to replace.

Comment: Thank you @Barmar for the comprehensive answer. I confused yield behavior with execution(console.log), your example explains this very well!

Comment: I have to agree that it's confusing the way the `yield` keyword does double duty, performing both control flow and as an implicit argument.